# Error while uploading document to SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, upload, sharepoint-2013

I am getting the following error while uploading file from local computer to share point. i am using CSOM with C#.

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream =
            new FileStream(@"C:\sage\uploaded.docx", FileMode.Open))
                SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext,
                    "/Shared Documents/uploaded.docx", fileStream, true);
        }
```

I already set "full control" permission on Web, Lists and Site Collection

Comment: This is your code in a web-part? You can also try running your code with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Comment: this is in code behind file but i have done file uploading using CSOM. using this method i think i don't have privileges.

Comment: So that your code needs to be in a web-part to get the context of the currently logged in user.
This way you're doing, trying to save this file in a biblioca as if it were anonymous.
understand?